# UIAlertView crash iOS7 - Assertion failure

Tags: uikit, ios7, uialertview, uikeyboard, assertion

I have a problem regarding the `UIAlertView` on iOS7.
When I launch my application, it crashes with the following message:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTask:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:388
```

The error occurs on the following line:

```
- (IBAction)updatePositions:(id)sender{
     _alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"text" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
     [_alert show];     <====== IT CRASHS HERE
     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateDataThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

I'm using ARC and the property `_alert` is set defined as: `@property (nonatomic,strong)`

This error seems strange, because on iOS6 the code works perfectly and I don't know what should be different on iOS7.

Does anyone have an idea what could the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same error, and the issue was that the UIAlertView was attempting to be shown from a thread which wasn't the main thread.

The crash however wouldn't always occur, only when a first AlertView was already being shown while this second AlertView was trying to pop up as well.

In my case, a simple fix was to do:

```
    //Your code here
    ...

    //Alert
    _alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"text" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //Show alert here
       [_alert show];
       });

    //Resume your code here
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem after forgetting that I was working from a background thread. I don't know if that's the case here, but I'd make sure you're not trying to call updatePositions: from anything other than the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this :

```
_alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"text" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[_alert show];
```

removing [[ and ]] around @"text"

But, your I don't think your problem came from this UIAlertView.

Comment: Thank you,I removed the [] around text, but as you mentioned that was not the problem...

Comment: did you try to override a method of the UIAlertView delegate ?

Comment: no I have not "overrided" any method of the UIAlertView. The strange thing is, in my application I haved used many times this syntax to show an alertview. When I uncomment this lines, my app runs normal and it shows other alertviews without crashing. In addition I noticed, when I reset my iOS simulator, and reinstall the app. The application will NOT crash for the first time... When I close and reopen the app, that it starts crashing with this error. It seems so strange...

Comment: Could the problem be connected with the message:
Cannot find executable for CFBundle ...CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded).
I don't think so, but maybe?

Comment: sry I updated the code from my first post, now it's the complete code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well but not too familiar with the method dispatch_async. I used

[alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

and the problem hasn't come up again.

Answer (score 0):

Put your alertview code in a separate function like

```
-(void)showAlert
{
  _alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"text" message:nil delegate:self    cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
   [_alert show];
}
```

Then in your IBAction do this

```
- (IBAction)updatePositions:(id)sender
{
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateDataThread) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title" message:@"Your message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

However, if you need to show the same alert in multiple places it's better to create a separate function for it.